# Need a MySQL query to give more readable results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got a MySQL database with tables 'people', 'questions', and 'answers'. I have this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName) as Name, people.emailAddress, questions.fruit, answers.fruitID, answers.info, answers.dateLogged, questions.fruitID, questions.questionairID, questions.person
From answers
Join questions ON answers.fruitID= questions.fruitID
JOIN people ON questions.person= people.personID
WHERE questions.questionairID= '24' 
ORDER BY people.personID
```

Which produces this result:

```
+------------------+--------------------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------+
|       Name       |    emailAddress    | fruit  | fruitInstanceID |       info        |    dateLogged     | fruitInstanceID | questionairID | person |
+------------------+--------------------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------+
| Harry Potter     | hpotter@gmail.com  | apple  |             107 | NULL              | 05/26/17 07:23 PM |             107 |            24 |      6 |
| Ron Weasley      | rweasley@gmail.com | apple  |             113 | NULL              | 05/26/17 06:30 PM |             113 |            24 |      8 |
| Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | apple  |             116 | NULL              | 05/26/17 06:29 PM |             116 |            24 |      9 |
| Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | orange |             114 | NULL              | 05/26/17 06:36 PM |             114 |            24 |      9 |
| Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | apple  |             116 | NULL              | 05/26/17 08:28 PM |             116 |            24 |      9 |
| Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | orange |             114 | NULL              | 05/26/17 08:28 PM |             114 |            24 |      9 |
| Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | orange |             114 | some extra info   | 05/26/17 08:29 PM |             114 |            24 |      9 |
| Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | orange |             114 | more extra info   | 05/26/17 08:29 PM |             114 |            24 |      9 |
| Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | orange |             114 | NULL              | 05/26/17 08:31 PM |             114 |            24 |      9 |
| Severus Snape    | ssnape@gmail.com   | apple  |             119 | NULL              | 05/26/17 06:37 PM |             119 |            24 |     10 |
| Severus Snape    | ssnape@gmail.com   | orange |             117 | NULL              | 05/26/17 06:46 PM |             117 |            24 |     10 |
| Severus Snape    | ssnape@gmail.com   | orange |             117 | user entered info | 05/26/17 06:46 PM |             117 |            24 |     10 |
| Severus Snape    | ssnape@gmail.com   | orange |             117 | more user info    | 05/26/17 06:46 PM |             117 |            24 |     10 |
| Severus Snape    | ssnape@gmail.com   | orange |             117 | info again        | 05/26/17 06:46 PM |             117 |            24 |     10 |
| Remus Lupin      | rlupin@gmail.com   | apple  |             122 | NULL              | 05/26/17 06:29 PM |             122 |            24 |     11 |
| Viktor Krum      | vkrum@gmail.com    | apple  |             125 | NULL              | 05/26/17 06:30 PM |             125 |            24 |     12 |
| Molly Weasley    | mweasley@gmail.com | apple  |             128 | NULL              | 05/26/17 06:36 PM |             128 |            24 |     13 |
| Molly Weasley    | mweasley@gmail.com | apple  |             128 | NULL              | 05/26/17 07:22 PM |             128 |            24 |     13 |
| Molly Weasley    | mweasley@gmail.com | orange |             126 | NULL              | 05/26/17 07:37 PM |             126 |            24 |     13 |
| Molly Weasley    | mweasley@gmail.com | orange |             126 | NULL              | 05/26/17 07:37 PM |             126 |            24 |     13 |
| Oliver Wood      | owood@gmail.com    | apple  |             131 | NULL              | 05/26/17 06:33 PM |             131 |            24 |     14 |
| Oliver Wood      | owood@gmail.com    | banana |             133 | NULL              | 05/26/17 06:33 PM |             133 |            24 |     14 |
+------------------+--------------------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------+
```

And that's great. It has all the info I need (and more) but a more readable format would be nice. What query can I use to get me something more like this:

```
+------------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+
|       Name       |    emailAddress    | Apple | Orange | Banana |
+------------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+
| Harry Potter     | hpotter@gmail.com  | YES   |        |        |
| Ron Weasley      | rweasley@gmail.com | YES   |        |        |
| Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | YES   | YES    |        |
| Severus Snape    | ssnape@gmail.com   | YES   | YES    |        |
| Remus Lupin      | rlupin@gmail.com   | YES   |        |        |
| Viktor Krum      | vkrum@gmail.com    | YES   |        |        |
| Molly Weasley    | mweasley@gmail.com | YES   | YES    |        |
| Oliver Wood      | owood@gmail.com    | YES   |        | YES    |
+------------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Or bonus, also count the number of times for the fruits:

```
+------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+
|       Name       |    emailAddress    |  Apple  | Orange  | Banana |
+------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+
| Harry Potter     | hpotter@gmail.com  | YES     |         |        |
| Ron Weasley      | rweasley@gmail.com | YES     |         |        |
| Hermione Granger | hgranger@gmail.com | YES (2) | YES (5) |        |
| Severus Snape    | ssnape@gmail.com   | YES     | YES (4) |        |
| Remus Lupin      | rlupin@gmail.com   | YES     |         |        |
| Viktor Krum      | vkrum@gmail.com    | YES     |         |        |
| Molly Weasley    | mweasley@gmail.com | YES (2) | YES (2) |        |
| Oliver Wood      | owood@gmail.com    | YES     |         | YES    |
+------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for first case -

```
SELECT CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName) as Name, 
people.emailAddress,
(CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'apple' THEN 'YES'
    ELSE ''
END) as Apple,
(CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'orange' THEN 'YES'
    ELSE ''
END) as Orange,
(CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'banana' THEN 'YES'
    ELSE ''
END) as Banana
From answers
Join questions ON answers.attackID = campaign.attackID 
JOIN employees ON campaign.employee = employees.employeeID 
WHERE campaign.campaignID = '24' 
ORDER BY employees.employeeID
```

Not sure how count would work in second case. But I think it will be group by on employeeid.

**UPDATE**

For second case I don't think there is need for text 'YES', count of fruit should be enough to decide. Try this for count -

```
SELECT CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName) as Name, 
people.emailAddress,
SUM(CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'apple' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) as 'AppleCount',
SUM(CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'orange' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) as 'OrangeCount',
(CASE questions.fruit 
    WHEN 'banana' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) as 'BananaCount'
From answers
Join questions ON answers.attackID = campaign.attackID 
JOIN employees ON campaign.employee = employees.employeeID 
WHERE campaign.campaignID = '24'
GROUP BY employees.employeeID 
ORDER BY employees.employeeID
```

---

Comment: I'll try this in a few minutes. I forgot to update some of the fields in the query for my example. That's why you saw employeeid instead of personID which makes more sense in the question. .

Comment: This worked great! The first result listed all records for the people (so I had several rows for Hermione and others) but I think I can fix that with a group by maybe. The second one worked perfect. Thanks!

Comment: My earlier edit was rejected for "deviating from the original intent of the post," but the update to your answer is missing the `SUM` for `BananaCount` - the result being that it is not the aggregate function you clearly meant it to be.  Otherwise it should work just fine.

Comment: Ah, yep, good catch! I've got the change in my query. Thanks!